# Горизонтальный RecyclerView внизу RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Есть `fragment` на котором есть два элемента отображены в `xml`.
Первый (кастомный) привязан "наверху":

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Второй (RecyclerView) привязан "внизу":

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Но проблема в том, что если я задаю (как мне нужно) параметр высоты как `wrap_content` он занимает все свободное пространство и отображается "сверху" (поверх первого элемента), если же задам высоту как константу - то отображается, как положено снизу.

`xml` фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              >

    <com.luxary_team.openweather.ui.view.CurrentWeatherView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.luxary_team.openweather.ui.view.CurrentWeatherView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_general_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Вопрос: что нужно добавить или изменить что бы при параметре `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` горизонтальный `RecyclerView` отображался внизу?

`xml` элемента `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="48dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_text_view_list_item_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="ПТ"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottomUnactiveListItem"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_image_view_list_item_bottom"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/testicon"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature_text_view_list_item_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="16 C"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия сапорт либ? Если я правильно помню RecyclerView научился правильно работать с `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` только начиная с версии 23.4.0. Хотя это касалось вертикального режима, в горизонтальном не уверен что `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` работает правильно.

Comment: можете попробовать "верх" RecyclerView привязать к "низу" CurrentWeatherView

Comment: @metalurgus Можно- я вами согласен. Но меня интересует все таки возможность отображения, в котором нижний список был привязан к "дну" экрана и в

Comment: @xkor Версия 23.2.1. Но у меня studio отображает ее как последнюю.

Comment: значит давно SDK не обновляли, последняя 24.2.1

Comment: Android Support Library, revision 24.2.1 (September 2016) - последняя - сейчас поставим и попробуем

Comment: @xkor оформите пожалуйста ваш совет как ответ. Он действительно подошел, правда пришлось попотеть со всеми настройками gradle и прочими делами, тем не менее то что вы указали оказалось очень важным! Благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно помню RecyclerView научился правильно работать с `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` только начиная с версии 23.4.0. Хотя это касалось вертикального режима, в горизонтальном не уверен что `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` работает правильно.

В общем попробуйте использовать последнюю версию сапорт либ. На данный момент это 24.2.1.